# UICollectionView changes content offset when rotated

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, screen-rotation

I have a `UICollectionViewController` subclass embedded in another view controller. It seems that no matter what I do, the collection view shifts its frame upward by 128px each time I rotate the device to landscape. I've turned off "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in both the parent view controller and the (child) collection view controller.

What am I missing? Where should I look to find the source of this mysterious frame modification? I'm all out of ideas myself.

Comment: got solution? I am facing same issue using auto layout.